# Should I really mark this answer "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed [a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13270152) today's morning. I thought several times before reviewing this answer. But it is recommending a tutorial link. So, I recommend it for deletion.

I am still think it is a low quality post and it should be in comment as it is referring to a tutorial site.

Is it really a High quality post? Should I really mark this answer "Looks OK"?

I just asking it for self-improvement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nothing wrong with recommending a tutorial in an answer. Recommending a tutorial *instead* of answering is pretty dodgy, but that's not what happened here.

Answer (score 2):

The user gave a better idea about semaphores and where the question needed them. Used in the application layer for asking DB about the statuses. Then explained it in a abstract way.

At the end he gave the tutorial link for complete understanding. If he tried to write the whole tutorial inside the answer then how would the question poster know where to start or what to pick.

So in my opinion after reading the question and the answer, the answer is good. Explaining the important part and then referring further reading.